# NSSegmentedControl image default size?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstoolbar, nssegmentedcontrol

What is the recommended size for NSSegmentedControl segment image?

```
- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)image
  forSegment:(NSInteger)segment
```

I'm currently using 26x26 PNG image and it looks blurry.

[image: My app]

What I want is :

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer on Apple's HIG

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ToolbarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH89-SW1

I used 19x19 template image and worked fine.

Comment: An updated direct link: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/custom-icons/#segmented-control-icons